# How to use Microsoft Flow on SharePoint list to create event in SharePoint calendar

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

I am new to SharePoint and Flow, this is my first project using the two, so I really have no idea what to do.

I created a SharePoint site of 198 calendars, using SharePoint online, and am trying to create a central list where events can be entered and a flow will create the events in the proper calendar.

I have a list called Event List where users will enter the title, location, start and end time of an event. I would then like the flow to link the location to the title of the calendar (location:00 calendar:Store 00), and create the event using the title, start and end time.

[image: Event List with Test Event]
[image: Test Store 500 Calendar]

Below is a non-working example of what I am trying to do. I don't want to set the list name but want the flow to find the calendar based on the location in the event list.

[image: Non-working flow]

Comment: Currently I have created a single flow for each calendar. It works for now until a better solution can be figured out.

Answer (score 0):

A simple demo for your reference, you could get the item data from Dynamic Content.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question to better explain what I am trying to achieve. If your answer still applies would you please help me understand? Thank you for taking the time to answer.

Comment: Not so clear about your description, when I did test, Flow won't list calendar list, it works fine by 'Enter custom value'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Flow currently supports selecting either the list or the SharePoint site url. Workarounds include creating an azure function that adds the item to the calendars, and calling that function from a flow, or perhaps calling the SharePoint rest api from flow.

Answer (score 0):

This may depend on the type of list you are trying to connect to.

The SharePoint connectors only support "**List**" but not "**Events List**" type lists.

If you have created a "Calendar" in SharePoint - that usually comes through as an "**Events List**"

Note in my screenshot - "Birthdays and Work Anniver" is a Calendar - where "BDandHD" is a List.
[image]

The SharePoint connectors will only recognize the **List** type and not the **Events List**, though I have been able to access some if I am only writing TO an **Events List**.

Here I can create an item in an **Events List** (Though only "Lists" are shown in Auto-Complete, not "Events List", so I had to enter the list name as a Custom Value)
[image]
[image: Only "Lists" are shown in Auto-Complete, not "Events List"]

But trying to pull back a list of the current events - so I don't overwrite an existing entry - fails.
[image]

Even though it is accessed by a similar URL plan to a "normal" list

[image]

I suspect this is something related to the Graph API not recognizing it as a proper "List" - but I am not certain.

My best idea for how to functionally accomplish "Getting a list of events in an **Event List**" would be maybe use the Subscribe in Outlook feature of the Calendar, and then try to query that from Shared Calendar APIs in Outlook - but you won't have as much detail of Item ID and such - and linking to the specific item would probably require putting an ID value or link into the Description of every event on the calendar, or more being [available to the SharePoint Connector](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepoint/) - though I guess that would probably also depend on more being [Available in Graph](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sharepoint)